# Does getPriceAmountMicros() include local taxes for skus of type subscription?

Tags: android-billing

I've been using the Android billing client for a while now and always display the prices using [getPriceAmountInMicros()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/SkuDetails.html#getPriceAmountMicros()) from the `SkuDetails` object returned from the billing client.

Often we get complains from some of the customers that the price we display is not the same price they're paying. I've always assumed this is due to local taxes and that the Google play Store doesn't return the prices with local taxes included.

However, going to the documentation of `getPriceAmountInMicros()` things start to get a bit fuzzy. In particular this section:

> This value represents the localized, rounded price for a particular currency.

What is a "localized price"? Is this including taxes? I cannot find any explicit place where it says this includes taxes or that it doesn't. By contrast the documentation for [getPrice()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/SkuDetails.html#getPrice()) explicitly states that the price **does not** include taxes.

Looking into a completely different resource, yet connected to a sku, one can see the same method - [getPriceAmountInMicros()](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/androidpublisher/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/androidpublisher/model/SubscriptionPurchase.html#getPriceAmountMicros--). In this method, it's explicitly stated that the price does not include taxes. It would seem odd to me that they would choose to name the method in a `SkyDetails` object the same, but have different semantics. Nevertheless, I want to be sure and would highly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out.

Because the QPS of computing taxes during skuDetails queries would be high, our servers defer tax computation to the purchase flow. So unless you need `getPriceAmountMicros()` for, say, refunds; you should simply use `getPrice()`.

Comment: But does it mean then that the method really doesn't return the price with taxes?

Comment: I'm just double checking because here in Germany there's also a tax, but I swear that when I go in my app's subscription page I see the price I'm paying for.

Comment: That's correct, none of the methods return taxes. But you can verify this as well. Try buying an item from any app and as part of the checkout flow it will show, e.g., ` $99.99/year + tax (i)`. So the methods in SkuDetails will only return the values that you specify through the Play Console. All taxes are computed during the purchase flow.

Comment: That's weird, the `getPrice` method gives me the price after applying the tax (VAT).
but in the documentation, they stated that the price doesn't include tax.
What kind of tax do they mean!